# What does "build products" mean in git-clean manpage?

Tags: git

> This allows removing all untracked files, including build products.

This is a sentence to explain `-x` option of `git-clean`. What does the "build proudcts" mean here? I read the text several times, and I still don't quite understand without a clear context.

Answer (score 1):

'build products' in that context might be any files created by the build process, like executables or temporary files. git-clean removes them if they're not part of the repo already.